# Inequality involving triangle and the sum $a^2+b^2+c^2$

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles, area, geometric-inequalities

Weitzenbock's inequality states: given $S$ the area of a triangle, and $a,b,c$ the sides of the triangle, the following inequality holds:
$$a^2+b^2+c^2\ge 4S\sqrt3$$
and the Gordon's inequality states:
$$ab+bc+ca\ge4S\sqrt3$$
But we know that:
$$a^2+b^2+c^2\ge ab+bc+ca,$$ so the question is: is it known some other sharper inequality for the sum: $a^2+b^2+c^2$ where $a,b,c$ are the triangle's sides?

Comment: For one, if someone is looking $a^2+b^2+c^2 \ge kS$ the maximum of $k$ is $4\sqrt{3}$ because the inequality can hold.

Comment: yes, you can have an equilateral triangle -- then all inequalities hold as equalities, so $4\sqrt{3}$ is sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the following?

$$2(ab+ac+bc)-a^2-b^2-c^2\geq4\sqrt3S$$