Prove Inequality: $\frac{1}{3} \le \frac{a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2}}{(a + b + c)^{2}} < \frac{1}{2}$

Prove the Inequality:
$$\frac{1}{3} \le \frac{a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2}}{(a + b + c)^{2}} < \frac{1}{2}$$where $a,b,c$ are the three sides of a triangle.

My attempt:
$(a+b+c)^{2} \le 3a^{2}+3b^{2}+3c^{2}$
$a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+2ab+2bc+2ac \le 3a^{2}+3b^{2}+3c^{2}$
$2ab+2bc+2ac \le 2a^{2}+2b^{2}+2c^{2}$
$ab+bc+ac \le a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}$

No doubt someone will come along in a minute and write out a solution but in the spirit of helping, there are two tricks I think of straight away (as a matter of experience). First is to think of the numbers in the form $a/(a+b+c)$, so that they sum to 1. This is a well known step/technique. Second is to try AM-GM or standard variants. Do you know these (so called ‘power mean’) inequalities?

You are almost there, observe that $ab<\dfrac{a^2+b^2}{2}$ (which holds for any real numbers, not just triangle side).
For the other side, try this link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1697113/inequality-involving-triangle-and-the-sum-a2b2c2?noredirect=1 (which maybe an overkill).

Here is a continuation of your attempt (somehow similar to Angae's comment):
$$ab+bc+ac \le a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}$$
$$0\le 2a^2+2b^2+2c^2-2ab-2bc-2ac$$
$$0\le(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(a-c)^2$$
Now we need to prove $\frac{a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2}}{(a + b + c)^{2}} < \frac{1}{2}
$.

HINT.-Since $(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+ac+bc)$ we can get
$$\frac{1}{3} \le \frac{a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2}}{(a + b + c)^{2}} < \frac{1}{2}\iff\frac12\lt\frac{ab+ac+bc}{a^2+b^2+c^2}\le1$$
First $\underline{\dfrac12\lt\dfrac{ab+ac+bc}{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$
One has $a^2+b^2+c^2\lt2(ab+ac+bc)\iff(a-b)^2+c^2\lt2(a+b)c=2(c+h)c=2c^2+2ch$ for some $h\gt0$ then
$(a-b)^2\lt c^2+2ch\implies a-b\lt c$ which is proper to triangles (the same is valid for the three sides).
Second $\underline{\dfrac{ab+ac+bc}{a^2+b^2+c^2}\le1}$
The maximum of LHS is clearly reached when the triangle is equilateral (it can be calculated otherwise) so in other cases we must have $\dfrac{ab+ac+bc}{a^2+b^2+c^2}\lt1$.

$\dfrac{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}{(a + b + c)^2}=\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{2(ab+ac+bc}{a^2+b^2+c^2}}=\dfrac{1}{1+2X}$
$$\dfrac{1}{1+2X}\lt\frac12\implies2\lt1+2X\implies\frac12\lt X\\frac13\le\dfrac{1}{1+2X}\implies1+2X\le3\implies X\le1$$ Thus $\boxed{\dfrac12\lt X\le1}$
The most mediocre thing in mathematics is to describe what is correct as wrong.
